# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException after reading a line and put it in two dimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Here's an example:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
          java.io.File file = new java.io.File("lcs.txt");

         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
         String line;
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {


          String str1= line.substring(0, line.indexOf(":")); // company names

          String str2= line.substring(line.indexOf(":")+2); 
          String[][] array = null;
          for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++)
          {
          array[i][0]= str1.toString();
            for(int j=1;j<array[i].length;j++){
               array[i][j]=str2.split("\\)"+","+"\\(").toString();
                System.out

.println(array[i][j]+ " ");
        }
```

The file looks like this

```
 Nike:(jeans,200),(shirt,100),(jacket,350),(hat,80),(shoes,200)
   Mango:(dress,600),(dress,600),(skirt,200),(shirt,120)
   Dior:(jacket,400),(jacket,400),(shoes,100)
```

The idea is to get the items into an array so the longest common sub-sequence function can be applied to the array items , and the result will be shown as company name .

Thanks

Comment: `String[][] array = null;` May a time to read a tutorial about arrays. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: you dont have your array initialized...

Comment: @user3075254 Read the link I provided in comments.

Comment: it has to read it from a file so why to initialize it ?

Comment: You need to understand how objects work.  You can't put anything into a `null` array.

Comment: if i remove null it gives me error . actually am new to programming world .

Comment: You have to think to the array "String[][]" like a virtual memory address and not really the space in which put data. This space must be inizialized in such a way to allow "array[offset1][offset2]" within space starting from the base address I said before. Pratically is more tricky because arrays of objects like Strings are different from arrays of primitive datas, but you can start think in this way.

Comment: you need to read up on the basics... Obviously this project is too complicated for you at this stage. Just do some basic stuff with arrays and try to understand how they work ;-)

Comment: How to debug `NullPointerException`: 1. Go to the line reported in the exception trace. 2. Find all uses of the dot (`.`) operator, for instance `array.length`. 3. Check if any expression preceding a dot operator evaluates to `null`. 4. Find out why that expression evaluates to `null` at that point in the code.

There may be some other causes too, but this simple algorithm should help you in your early programming adventures.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you do `String[][] array = null` then immediately check if `i<array.length`, but since `array` is `null`, `array.length` throws the `NullPointerException`

To initialize the `String[][]` properly, do something like: `String[][] array = new String[x][y]` where x and y are the sizes of the arrays.